# Apache in Docker says: Symbolic link not allowed

Tags: apache, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I use a Docker image: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/fec7f537f049aafd2102202519c3ca9cb9576707/5.5/apache/Dockerfile

And i use it with docker-compose:

```
apache:
  build: ./site/docker/apachephp
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.test.dev
  volumes:
    - ./site/code:/var/www/app
  expose:
    - "80"
```

The code is a symfony app and uses symbolic link in the web folder, but for all assets in the symbolic links i get in the apache logs:

AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/app/web/test

All other code runs fine.
I wonder if that *Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch* is used correct and if there maybe other config files that override someting?

Or is it some Permission issue?
The files on the host belong not to the apache user www-data but to another user, read rights are set however.

The Apache config is:

```
# see http://sources.debian.net/src/apache2/2.4.10-1/debian/config-dir/apache2.conf

Mutex file:/var/lock/apache2 default
PidFile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User www-data
Group www-data
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# ports.conf
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/app>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /var/www/app/web

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 combined

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

# Multiple DirectoryIndex directives within the same context will add
# to the list of resources to look for rather than replace
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php index.php index.html

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Have you entered the running container and checked the configuration which is used inside the container. Sometimes it is a bit confusing where to place a config or how to reference it correctly. My best practice when I got trouble like this is, runn the container go in it with docker exec -i -t containername /bin/bash and have a look whats going on in there.

Comment: I would use `docker exec -ti <container name>` to inspect the path inside the container and see what's there and where the links are set.  You can get the container name from `docker ps`.

Comment: good idea guys, ill try tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:
thanks to the tips in the comments above, i logged in the container and checked the pathes and the symlinks were pathes of the host, so that couldnt work.

So i probably have to create the symlinks in the container, unless there is some way to tell docker to follow symlinks from the host, but i doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with symbolic links, and in my case it was because the link was with a physical path from the root of the system, and Docker somehow virtualizes the paths of the instance. As follows:

analyticsSync -> /media/user/DATA/dev/web/ic/analytics/public/sync/analyticsSync

I solved it by creating the relative symbolic link:

analyticsSync -> ic/analytics/public/sync/analyticsSync

"/media/user/DATA" is the physical path of my data partition, which is not recognized by Docker.

I hope it helps.