# Docker-compose build fails because of container-created link in a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, docker-volume

I have a setup where airflow is running in docker container and has it's logs directory mapped to directory in host. While running, it creates a file system link `/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler/latest` that has a valid target inside a container, but not in host. Next time running `docker-compose build` it trips on that link and fails the build.

I've tried ignoring logs directory in .dockerignore, but that did not change anything.

Relevant parts of my setup are as follows:

Working directory

```
***/docker/
  airflow/
    logs/
      scheduler/
        ...
        2018-01-30/
        latest -> /usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler/2018-01-30
    .dockerignore
    Dockerfile
    ...
  docker-compose.yml
  ...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    ...
    airflow:
        ...
        build:
            dockerfile: airflow/Dockerfile
            context: .
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        volumes:
            - ./airflow/logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs/
            ...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.8.1

USER root
...
RUN chown -R airflow: /usr/local/airflow
USER airflow
...
```

.dockerignore

```
./logs
...
```

Error I get in terminal:

```
$ pwd
/***/docker
$ docker-compose build
Building airflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
    command()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 254, in build
    build_args=build_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 364, in build
    service.build(no_cache, pull, force_rm, memory, build_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 967, in build
    'memory': parse_bytes(memory) if memory else None
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 150, in build
    path, exclude=exclude, dockerfile=dockerfile, gzip=gzip
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 14, in tar
    root=root, fileobj=fileobj, gzip=gzip
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 103, in create_archive
    'Can not access file in context: {}'.format(full_path)
IOError: Can not access file in context: /***/docker/airflow/logs/scheduler/latest
```

If I delete contents of `airflow/logs/` before running `docker-compose build` everything works and airflow creates same link again and I have to keep deleting it.

I'd like docker-compose to completely ignore `airflow/logs` directory. And ideally, in host, to not have a file system link airflow created from inside container.

**EDIT** in response to my question getting flagged as a potential duplicate of [Mount host directory with a symbolic link inside in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container)

- I am not trying to make a container work with a link in the host. Container creates the link (although I agree root cause for link being broken in host would be same for both questions);
- I don't want the link to work on both container and host. I don't really care that host has a broken symlink. I want that link, or ideally entire `airflow/logs` directory to be ignored by docker;
- I can't just create a dummy directory on host to cheat my way out of this because airflow will change target of that link every day;
- Accepted answer in the linked question does not give a solution all it says is "don't use symlinks with targets that would have different path on host and container". I'm not in control of that symlink. Airflow is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount host directory with a symbolic link inside in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.dockerignore` may not be taking effect since the build context you have set for airflow is `.`, which is not the same directory as where your `.dockerignore` file is. Docker compose is looking for your `.dockerignore` file in the location relative to the build context.

In your `docker-compose.yml`, try setting your build context to `./airflow` and dockerfile to `Dockerfile`.

```
airflow:
    ...
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        context: ./airflow
```

This should help Docker Compose find your `.dockerignore` file at build time.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your .dockerignore file is being ignored by docker daemon. Try changing ./logs to ./airflow/logs/**

[here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) is link to .dockerignore docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That did not work though. At this point I've tried `**/logs/**/*` as well. This symlink will break other services in docker-compose.yml as well if their `context` can reach it.

Comment: Does \**/logs/**/\* solve your problem? if yes, then you can try moving your .dockerignore file to same level as of your docker-compose.yml

Comment: Having `.dockerignore` in the same level as `docker-compose.yml` did help. Looks like it's because `context` for airflow service is pointing to it.

Comment: Glad it helped. When you specify . as context, it is directory of docker-compose.yaml, so yes it is context thing