# how to share an external file in the disk into a running docker container?

Tags: docker

I am currently running a docker container with a specific folder shared to it. However, I need to access other folders which are not in the shared folder.

Does docker mount or docker volume help in any way to mount a file into a running docker container?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

- just copy the file and paste it the shared location, it will be available for use in docker mount location.
- copy the host file to the container where you want, using

```
docker cp your_local_file containerid:/path/to/container
```

There are other ways around but that will not be that easy as these two approaches.

You can check this details article but I think it will take your handsome time to that each and every time.

[mount-volumes-into-a-running-container](https://medium.com/kokster/mount-volumes-into-a-running-container-65a967bee3b5)

You can also check

[docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking one alternative could be to use soft links by placing them inside your mounted volume but it won't work as documented in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container). A suggested alternative is to mount your folders as different volumes:

`-v /home/test/:/home/test -v /mnt/mountedfile:/mnt/mountedfile`