# Images inside a docker volume are not served by a docker php application

Tags: php, docker

I'm running a custom Docker image based on the official php-fpm image, with just minor tweaks. Inside the host machine I have a folder containing some images I would like to server, so I am running the container and binding the host image folder to a folder in my container like `/home/host/images:/var/www/storage/images`. This goes well and if I bash into the container I see the files there.

My problem comes when I symlink the folder from the public folder in the container like `ln -s /var/www/storage/images /var/www/public/images`.
The link seems correct and I can navigate there using the shell and see for example my `test.png` image, but whenever I try to server any image for example `https://my-web-app.com/images/test.png` I get a 404.

However, from inside the containers shell I've created another folder like `/var/www/storage/images2` and then moved `test.png` and then updated my link like `ln -s /var/www/storage/images /var/www/public/images2` and then tested `https://my-wen-app.com/images/test.png` and it works!

Why can't I link my bound folder but I can link this new folder that I just created? Is there anything else to do when binding to allow this link to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount host directory with a symbolic link inside in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found the solution and was not related to the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the cause.
The symlink was working perfectly, the problem was that the container schema was: one container running `php-fpm` and another container running `nginx` the main folder was being bound to both containers but the images folder was just mounted to the `php-fpm` container so when the `nginx` container was asked for the images was not finding anything because it had no visibility of this volume.