# Mount Volume to Symbolic Link Location

Tags: docker, docker-compose, symlink

Using `docker-compose` I'm trying to mount my working directory that contains multiple directories and some are symbolic links.

For instance, I want to mount my working directory that has directories `A`, `B`, and `C`. However, directory `C` is a symbolic link to `C:\Users\MyUser\C`

Therefore, I would mount my directories like so:

```
volumes:
  - ../C:/mnt/host/c/Users/MyUser/C/ # Mounting to the symbolic link location
  - ./:/usr/src/app  # My working directory
```

This works fine. However, the issue is that `c/Users/MyUser` is dependent on the user that is executing the command. Therefore, a user would have to go in and update the file to something like `c/Users/SomeOtherUser` for it to still work. In other words, the directory I'm mounting it to is user dependent.

How can I decouple this from the User? It's fine to assume that the directory `C` will be in the User's `Home` directory and one level above the current directory. What I want to do is something like:

```
volumes:
  - ../C:/mnt/host/${PWD}/../C/
```

However, this won't work as it's not a valid syntax. How can I mount a Volume to the Symbolic Link's location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount host directory with a symbolic link inside in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container)

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks, but no I don't think so. What you linked assumes you can directly reference the absolute path. My issue is that the path is somewhat dynamic as I want to reference the User's home directory.